# Exceljs: Excel warning when opening file after some worksheets duplication

Tags: node.js, exceljs

I am using Exceljs to generate excelfiles. From other issues I found that there is no API for duplicating worksheets so I have to do it by copying model from base worksheet to the target one. This works fine but when opening new document there is a warning. Is there a method to get rid of it?

Warning:

[image]

Reproduction repo: [https://github.com/vladPopovschii/exceljs-issue](https://github.com/vladPopovschii/exceljs-issue/)

Similar discution: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/discussions/2030

ExcelJS: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs